# codeigniter dropdown order, value chosen on first dropdown musn't apear on 2nd one

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I need to set a four order choose of sports in gym, so i have to use four dropdown, i have te retrieve the list of data from database, it's an array drom database that containe 30 disciplines when i choose the fisrt one in the first dropdown the seconde dropdown musn't containe this value, and also when i choose a value from the 3rd dropdown this dropdown musn't containe value1 and value2 from dropdown1 and dropdown2, the same thing about the dropdown four it must containe only 27 values from database

My model : participantsport_m.php :

```
  public function get_new()

{

$participant_sport = new stdClass();

$participant_sport->nom = '';
$participant_sport->prenom = '';
$participant_sport->trimestres = '';
$participant_sport->sport_ordre1 = '';
$participant_sport->sport_ordre2 = '';
$participant_sport->sport_ordre3 = '';
$participant_sport->sport_ordre4 = '';
$participant_sport->sport_montant_paye = '';
$participant_sport->sport_debut_periode = '';
$participant_sport->sport_fin_periode = '';
  return $participant_sport;
}


    function get_discipline_sport() {
            $this ->db->select('id, nom_discipline');
            $query = $this ->db->get('disciplines_sport');

            $salles = array();

            if ($query->result()) {
                    foreach ($query->result() as $discipline) {
                      $disciplines[$discipline->id] = $discipline->nom_discipline;
                    }
                    return $disciplines;
            } else {
                    return FALSE;
            }
    }
```

The structure of database :
id  -  nom_discipline  -  tarif_discipline  -  description

My controller agent.php :

```
        public function inscriresport ($id = NULL)
        {

            // Fetch a participant or set a new one
            if ($id) {
                $this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get($id);
                count($this->data['participant_sport']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'Agent non trouvé';

            // explode to array
            // print_r($this->data['participant_sport']['trimestres[]']); // test before explode

              $this->data['participant_sport']->trimestres = explode(",", $this->data['participant_sport']->trimestres);

            // print_r($this->data['participant_sport']['trimestres[]']); // test after explode
            }
            else {
                $this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get_new();
            }

            // Set up the form
            $rules = $this->participantsport_m->rules_participantsport;
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

            // Process the form

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                $data = $this->participantsport_m->array_from_post(array('nom', 'prenom', 'beneficiaire', 'trimestres' , 'sport_ordre1', 'sport_ordre2', 'sport_ordre3', 'sport_ordre3',  ,'sport_montant_paye', 'sport_debut_periode', 'sport_fin_periode'));
                $this->participantsport_m->save($data, $id);
                redirect('admin/agent/profile/3608');
            }

            // Load the view
            $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/agent/inscriresport';
            $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
       }
```

And my view inscriresport.php :

```
                    <div class="widget-box">
                        <div class="widget-title">
                            <span class="icon">
                                <i class="icon-align-justify"></i>                                  
                            </span>
                            <h5><?php echo empty($participant->id) ? 'Nouveau Agent OCP:' : 'Modification de: ' . $participant_sport->nom.' '.$participant_sport->prenom; ?></h5>
                        </div>

                        <div class="widget-content nopadding">

                            <?php echo form_open(); ?>



                  <div  <?php if(form_error('nom')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?>>
                    <label class="control-label">Nom :</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                       <?php echo form_input('nom', set_value('nom', $this->input->get('nom') )); ?>
                       <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('nom'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div  <?php if(form_error('prenom')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?>>
                    <label class="control-label">Prenom :</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                       <?php echo form_input('prenom', set_value('prenom', $this->input->get('prenom') )); ?>
                       <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('prenom'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>




                        <div  <?php if(form_error('beneficiaire')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?>>
                          <label class="control-label">Bénéficiaire :</label>
                          <div class="controls">

                                                  <label><?php echo form_radio('beneficiaire', 'Agent', $this->input->get('beneficiaire') == 'Agent') ?> Agent </label>

                                                  <label><?php echo form_radio('beneficiaire', 'Conjoint', $this->input->get('beneficiaire')  == 'Conjoint') ?> Conjoint </label>

                                                  <label><?php echo form_radio('beneficiaire', 'Enfant', $this->input->get('beneficiaire')  == 'Enfant') ?> Enfant </label>
                                                  <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('beneficiaire'); ?></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>




              <div <?php if(form_error('trimestres[]')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?> >
                      <label class="control-label">Trimestres :</label>
                      <div class="controls" >

                      <?php $options = array(
                                          'trim1'  => ' Premier trimestre (Janv,Fév,Mars)',
                                          'trim2'    => ' Deuxiéme trimestre (Avril,Mai,Juin)',
                                          'trim3'   => ' Troisiéme trimestre (Juill,Aout,Sept)',
                                          'trim4' => ' Quatriéme trimestre (Oct,Nov,Déc)',
                                        );
                     echo form_multiselect('trimestres[]', $options , $this->input->post('trimestres') ? $this->input->post('trimestres') : $participant_sport->trimestres, 'id="trim"'); ?>
                      <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('trimestres[]'); ?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>


              <div <?php if(form_error('sport_ordre1')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?> >
                      <label class="control-label">Nom de la Salle :</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                      <?php echo form_dropdown('sport_ordre1', $countries , $this->input->post('sport_ordre1') ? $this->input->post('sport_ordre1') : $participant_salle->sport_ordre1 , 'id="ordre1"'); ?>
                      <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('sport_ordre1'); ?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div <?php if(form_error('sport_ordre2')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?> >
                      <label class="control-label">Nom de la Salle :</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                      <?php echo form_dropdown('sport_ordre2', $countries , $this->input->post('sport_ordre2') ? $this->input->post('sport_ordre2') : $participant_salle->sport_ordre2 , 'id="ordre2"'); ?>
                      <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('sport_ordre2'); ?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div <?php if(form_error('sport_ordre3')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?> >
                      <label class="control-label">Nom de la Salle :</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                      <?php echo form_dropdown('sport_ordre3', $countries , $this->input->post('sport_ordre3') ? $this->input->post('sport_ordre3') : $participant_salle->sport_ordre3 , 'id="ordre3"'); ?>
                      <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('sport_ordre3'); ?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div <?php if(form_error('sport_ordre4')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?> >
                      <label class="control-label">Nom de la Salle :</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                      <?php echo form_dropdown('sport_ordre4', $countries , $this->input->post('sport_ordre4') ? $this->input->post('sport_ordre4') : $participant_salle->sport_ordre4 , 'id="ordre4"'); ?>
                      <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('sport_ordre4'); ?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>




                        <div  <?php if(form_error('sport_montant_paye')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?>>
                          <label class="control-label">Montant à payé :</label>
                          <div class="controls">
                             <?php echo form_input('sport_montant_paye', set_value('sport_montant_paye', $participant_sport->sport_montant_paye)); ?>
                             <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('sport_montant_paye'); ?></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>






                        <div  <?php if(form_error('sport_debut_periode')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?>>
                          <label class="control-label">Debut période :</label>
                          <div class="controls">
                             <input type="text" name="sport_debut_periode" id="date3" value="<?php echo set_value('sport_debut_periode', $participant_sport->sport_debut_periode) ?>" />
                             <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('sport_debut_periode'); ?></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>




                        <div  <?php if(form_error('sport_fin_periode')) { echo 'class="control-group error"'; } else {echo 'class="control-group"';} ?>>
                          <label class="control-label">Fin période :</label>
                          <div class="controls">
                             <input type="text" name="sport_fin_periode" id="date4" value="<?php echo set_value('sport_fin_periode', $participant_sport->sport_fin_periode) ?>" />
                             <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('sport_fin_periode'); ?></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>






                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Enregistrer', 'class="btn btn-success"'); ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php echo form_close();?>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </br>
```

I need how can i do it by javascript i'm newbie on javascript and i don't know where i start, Any Help plsease? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to include all sports in all dropdowns and when you want to submit your form, go and check to see whether there are any same valued dropdowns or not. You can get them with:

```
var flag = false;

var e1 = document.getElementById("dropdown1 id");
var value1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;

var e2 = document.getElementById("dropdown2 id");
var value2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;

...

if(value1 != value2 && ...)
{
  flag = true;
}

if(flag)
{
  // Stuff
}
```

Comment: but how can i retrieve sports (an array of sports) from database into view? i guess that will be with javascript that i'm new

Comment: When you're loading your view in your controller you can pass an array of sports with form's extra data `load->view('view', $data);`. You can iterate and echo that array in your view to fill dropdowns.